# HTML button moves aftter being clicked on

Tags: javascript, css

I have 9 buttons looks like below:
[image: Before clicking]

However if I click on the button on top left, it becomes:
[image: After clicking]

I am really not sure why it moves when being clicked on and where the extra spaces are coming from.

Below is the sample code:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
buttons.forEach((b) => {
  b.addEventListener("click", onClick);
})

function onClick(event) {
    if(event.target) {
        event.target.innerText = "X";
    }
}
```

```css
.board {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: fit-content;
}

button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="board">
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <br>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <br>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your JSBin has only one button

Comment: Try adding this to the button class: `position: absolute;`

Comment: You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) intead of a link to jsbin.

Comment: I noticed there was only one button in my bin...  Fixed that now. Looking into Stack Snippet...

Comment: It seems to help if you give the buttons `vertical-align: top;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `vertical-align: baseline` is causing that. `bottom` fixes that issue.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
buttons.forEach((b) => {
  b.addEventListener("click", onClick);
})

function onClick(event) {
    if(event.target) {
        event.target.innerText = "X";
    }
}
```

```css
.board {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: fit-content;
}

button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none;
    vertical-align: bottom; /* Add this */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="board">
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <br>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <br>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Found [this post](https://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/) talks about what vertical-align is.

Answer (score -1):

Buttons by default have a display property of inline-block. That can sometimes lead to funky things based on the baseline of the text.

Try adding a {display: block} to your buttons. Or maybe a {display: flex}

```
button {
  display: flex;
}
```